# Sort the sequence alphabetically-Python

Tags: python, sorting

I want to write a python function that accepts a hyphen separated sequence of colors as input and returns the colors in a hyphen separated sequence after sorting them alphabetically

constraint: All colors will be completely in either lower case or upper case

sample input: `green-red-yellow-black-white`

sample output: `black-green-red-white-yellow`

My code -

```
my_str = input("Enter a string: ") 
words = [word.lower() for word in my_str.split()]
words.sort() 
print("The sorted words are:") 
for word in words: 
    print(word)
```

Comment: *"I want to write a python function…"* Please show us what you have written so far!

Comment: my_str = input("Enter a string: ")
words = [word.lower() for word in my_str.split()]
words.sort()
print("The sorted words are:")
for word in words:
 print(word)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works -

```
def str_sort(string):
  b = string.split('-')
  b.sort()
  c = '-'.join(b)
  return c

a = input('Enter a sequence of colors separated with hyphen: ')
str_sort(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem:

```
inputs = "green-red-yellow-black-white"

def sort_inputs(inputs):
    inputs_list = inputs.split('-')
    
    sorted_input = sorted(inputs_list)
    
    final = "-".join(term for term in sorted_input)
    
    return final

final = sort_inputs(inputs)

print(final)
```

Comment: Yeah, it is ok, I know :)